# Transfer Google Webmaster Tools data to another account

Tags: google-search-console

How can I transfer my Google Webmaster Tools data to another account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to do this today. It's an easy process. These are the steps I took:

- Log into your new account on GWT.
- Add your sites via the `Add a site...` button.

  - As you create each site entry, you will need to update your verification method. I used the HTML file upload method. This will tie that site into your new GWT account. The data is automatically visible in the NEW account.
- When your sites are created, click the `Add or remove owners` link beside each site (when on your dashboard) and then click the `Unverify` link, for the OLD account, under the **Verified owners** heading.

Answer (score 3):

The key point here is that there is no "transfer ownership" option.

The answer is that a site can have multiple owners in Google Webmaster Tools.

Therefore the most common "transfer" situation is simply to add another user at the higher permission level BUT if you want that user to be OWNER you cannot add them as owner - they have to add the site SEPARATELY by themselves **and they should not already be added as a user for that site**.

In other words if the user you want to transfer ownership to is already added as a user, then you must remove them. Then they must go add the site and follow the standard (multiple alternatives) verification, then if successful you will each be able to see each other as (co-)owners.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the property to the new Google account & verify it in google search console.
2. Delete the meta tag / html file / DNS record from the former account for the website.
3. Click on site url in google search console and then the toothed wheel > user and property owners
4. Click on the former owner email address and click on remove.